# Python filename if statement not working

Tags: python, windows

I have a python script that I need to run from the windows command line. The line

```
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "\\sampdirectory1\\sampdirectory2"):
  if filename.startswith("sample.csv"):
     os.remove("sample.csv")
```

keeps giving me the error

> The system cannot find the file specified 'sample.csv'

Well the file doesn't exist yet, it's created in the script for the first time then edited by the script every time after that. What I don't understand is why it's trying the do `os.remove` on `sample.csv`, when the *if* statement should fail, meaning the remove shouldn't be reached.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use `startswith` instead of checking the full filename? Is it possible there's a file called `sample.csv________` where `____` could be anything ?

Comment: No, thats not possible.

Comment: For one reason or another, you have a file named `r".\sampdirectory1\sampdirectory2\sample.csv" + something` where `something` could be an empty string. You cannot delete this file as `r".\sample.csv"` because that's not the same path.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete it while holding on to it because "On Windows, attempting to remove a file that is in use causes an exception to be raised"

```
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove
```

Comment: I'm not sure it exists, but should the if statement take care of that? What I'm not understanding is why the if statement is passing when the file DOESN't exits

Comment: @mrcrag  there is no need to check if the file exists as the loop is over the directory files.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 things to notice here:

first: the folder/destination are different. you should be using 
    os.remove(os.getcwd() + "\sampdirectory1\sampdirectory2" + "sample.csv")

second: a more elegant solution would be

```
try:
    os.remove(os.getcwd() + "\\sampdirectory1\\sampdirectory2" + "sample.csv")
except:
    print ('no such file/directory')
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

There might be a file `.\sampdirectory1\sampdirectory2\sample.csv`, so the condition is valid. But you're trying to delete a file `.\sample.csv` (*sample.csv* in current directory) that doesn't exist and you're getting the error.

Moreover, there might be a file `.\sampdirectory1\sampdirectory2\sample.csvSOMETHING`, so the condition is still valid and you're getting the error.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do `os.remove(filename)` instead of `os.remove("sample.csv")`
Because at first `sample.csv` is not the file that you are checking if it exists before removing. And even the filename is `sample.csv` you need to precise to full path of the file.

And as you are iterating over listing the directory files you don't need to check if the file exists.

So if you want to remove files whose names start with `sample.csv`, the code should be as below:

```
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "\\sampdirectory1\\sampdirectory2"):
    if filename.startswith("sample.csv"):
        os.remove(filename)
```

But if you want to remove only `sample.csv`, then you don't need any loop. Just do

```
filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "sampdirectory1\\sampdirectory2\\sample.csv")
if os.path.exists(filename):
     os.remove(filename)
```